# Samsung netbook NP300E5A dimming on battery

Tags: windows-7

My Samsung netbook NP300E5A screen is continually dimming.  The screen is forty percent dim on battery, but if I plug in the charger, the screen will be normal. I have tried all I know and I could not fix it. What should I do? what am trying to explain  is that the system is dimming like flooricent light  the screen resolution systems are all ok. When I pluging my charge the dimming we stop but when is on battery it look like flashing someone  light when driving

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have your power or display settings located in Control Panel set to have your screen dimmer when it is not connected to the charger.

That would make sense because the screen being less bright = more power conserved. When the computer is plugged in, it doesn't matter because it is actively charging thus, it can use as much power as it would like.

So, to resolve this navigate to Control Panel > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Click Change Advanced Power Settings > Expand the Display section, then expand the Enable Adaptive Brightness option. You can turn this off or on, and as I stated earlier, it is for conserving power.

Comment: Thanks for d reply, what am trying to explain  is that the system is dimming like flooricent light  the screen resolution systems are all ok. When I pluging my charge the dimming we stop but when is on battery it look like flashing someone  light when driving